# Reading into PHP from CSV in order to send SMS

Tags: php, csv, sms

I am working on some PHP code that will eventually send a SMS text which contains information taken from a CSV file.  Admittedly, PHP is not one of my strengths, to say the least.  The code snippet shows part of what I have thus far, where I'm trying to read from the CSV file into PHP.  (The CSV spreadsheet only has two (2) columns - one for the number, and one for the message that will be sent.)  I'm stuck on how to grab the CSV cell info into appropriate variables, and throwing them into the spots for the data to be sent by the SMS provider.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php

$file = fopen("txtmessage.csv","r");

 while(! feof($file))
   {
   (fgetcsv($file));   //This is where we grab the data from the CSV cells...
   }

 fclose($file);

$data = array(
  'User'          => XXXXXX,
  'Password'      => XXXXXX,
  'PhoneNumbers'  => //This is where we want to put the number captured from the CSV / XLS spreadsheet (Column 1)
  'Message'       => //This is where we want to put the message captured from the CSV / XLS spreadsheet (Column 2)
 'StampToSend'   => '9999999999',
 'MessageTypeID' => 1

...etc
  );
```

Comment: You need to assign the value $data = fgetcsv($file);

Comment: That makes sense.  Once I make this change to the while loop, how do I pull those values into the he '$data = array' variables ?

Comment: Look at the first example in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a `$data` array from each line of the CSV:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file);

    $data[] = array(
      'User'          => 'XXXXXX',
      'Password'      => 'XXXXXX',
      'PhoneNumbers'  => $line[0],
      'Message'       => $line[1],
      'StampToSend'   => '9999999999',
      'MessageTypeID' => 1);
}
```